# Read physical volume buttons in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I was wondering if there is a way to read the volume from the devices (Android & iOS) in Ionic and trigger a event when a volume button is pressed?

Answer (score -1):

You are going to have to look for the API or possible for a library to inherit the OS or Mobile OS you're coding for.  For example if you're going to managing an Android app or something on an Android device you'll need to be familiar with their APIs, here https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

Within you'll find a reference to the audio management here, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

I am sure you'll find something very similar for the iOS

Comment: You'll need to inject the Android/iOS needed libraries into your project. Forgot to add that as well.

Comment: The word "ionic" means nothing to you?